# Rviz doesn't start

Tags: ros, rviz, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing a package open_ptrack (https://github.com/OpenPTrack/open_ptrack) on my PC, Rviz didn't start. So, I downloaded a package rviz from the web site (http://wiki.ros.org/rviz) to compile the source with catkin_make, but Rviz doesn't start yet.
A terminal on my PC tells me next error.

```
ken@ken:~$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1396998258.516054297]: rviz version 1.11.0
[ INFO] [1396998258.516185316]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1396998259.050160910]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1396998259.050340409]: OpenGl version: 4.2 (GLSL 4.2).
*** glibc detected *** /home/ken/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rviz/rviz: corrupted double-linked list: 0x00000000017a85d0 ***
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 221: dl_open_worker: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args->nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!
```

The error explains that there is inconsistency on my PC. Does anyone have same experience as me? Doesn't anyone know the way to resolve it? or What's the cause? My PC has ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04. Thank you in advance!

In case of trying sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rviz

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-rviz : Depends: libassimp3 (>= 2.0.863) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libboost-filesystem1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libboost-program-options1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libboost-signals1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libboost-system1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libboost-thread1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libyaml-cpp0.3 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libyaml-cpp-dev but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150576/rviz-doesn%27t-start/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I strongly suggest installing rviz from debs rather than trying to build it from source. The source version likely has unreleased changes.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rviz
```

**EDIT**

An additional problem here was that the apt sources were not configured properly. In the apt sources.list, the codename must match the Ubuntu distribution (see the comments).

For additional help troubleshooting rviz, take a look at the rviz [troubleshooting guide](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-08**:
@ahendrix: I'm grateful for your quick response. I also tried it. I added the error to above article.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-08**:
@ahendrix: Your help seems to make me understand. There is no libassimp3 on Ubuntu 12.04 (precious). This package is installed on a quantal and later. The others are same reason as libassimp3. Why does rviz package require these package on Ubuntu 12.04? Thank you!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-08**:
It sounds like your package manager is in a bad state. You should probably try to figure that out. I would try installing rviz with aptitude, or trying to install each of the offending packages manually until you get a more useful error.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-08**:
I can install rviz without issues on Precise; on my machine, it depends on libassimp2. Perhaps you have the wrong distro name in your apt sources.list for ROS?

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-08**:
I checked a ros-latest.list in /etc/apt/souces.list.d. The article wrote the next sentence.

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu raring main
```

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-08**:
Yep, you have the wrong ubuntu version in your sources (raring instead of precise). That line should read:
`deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main`

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-08**:
@ahendrix: Thank you for your advice. I'd like you to convert your advice to answer. The advice means including apt sources.list for ROS.